# Render rdl in asp.net core 3

Tags: asp.net-core, reporting-services

How do I render a SSRS report in HTML format in an asp.net core 3 web app?

This link doesn't help since BasicHttpSecurityMode is not defined.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dataaccesstechnologies/2017/09/19/reporting-services-web-services-with-net-core-2/

This one is more promising.It uses URL access to render reports but it also renders the report parameters section in HTML mode which is not acceptable in my case.

https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2016/07/01/integrating-sql-server.aspx

I checked the REST services starting from SSRS 2017, but they are for meta data manipulation as far as I understood.